# Explaining usort() in detail

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, usort

Hi i'm currently trying to understand how the function I created "cmp()" works along with the function usort(). I just can't seem to get the logic. Can anybody help me out?

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
        echo "Iteration: " . $a . " > " . $b;
        if($a<$b)
        {
            echo " FALSE <br>";
        }
        elseif($a>$b)
        {
            echo " TRUE <br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo " ??? <br>";   
        }
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

// Sort and print the resulting array
echo "<pre>";
uasort($array, 'cmp');
echo "<br>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, as far as I can tell, and your `cmp()` function generates debug info every time. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: The order of iteration. That's what I've been wondering.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the algorithm it's using? I'm pretty sure all the PHP sorts use Quicksort.

Comment: On what it means if return 1, or return -1

Comment: Your `cmp()` function doesn't return `true`/`false`. Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: What does return 1 and -1 indicates

Comment: Have you seen this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cmp function doesn't do the sorting. It just tells usort if a value is smaller, equal or greater than another value.
The usort() function sorts an array using a user-defined comparison function.